# C++ SWAP Function does nothing?

Tags: c++, swap

For some reason this returns the original values, can someone tell me why? thank you! I set temp, not sure if this is right since num1 and num2 need to be set equal and they would both hold 1 value if I didn't.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap1(double& num1, double& num2);
void swap2(double& num1, double& num2);

double num1, num2;

int main(){
    cout << "Give me two numbers to swap: ";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    cout << "Original: " << num1 << ", " << num2 << endl;
    void swap1(double& num1, double& num2);
    cout << "First swap: " << num1 << ", " << num2 << endl;
    void swap2(double& num1, double& num2);
    cout << "Second swap: " << num1 << ", " << num2 << endl;


}

void swap1(double& num1, double& num2){
    double temp1;
    temp1 = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp1;
}

void swap2 (double& num1, double& num2){
    double temp2;
    temp2 = num1;
    num1 = num2;
    num2 = temp2;
}
```

Output: Sorry for bad formatting!

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/ASSIGN#31.cpp
Give me two numbers to swap: 10 20
Original: 10, 20
First swap: 10, 20
Second swap: 10, 20
```

Comment: `void swap1(double& num1, double& num2);` in your main function is a function declaration, not a function call

Comment: Not worth the downvotes and close votes. It's an MCVE and the error is not obvious for a beginner because there aren't even compiler warnings.

Comment: @Justin I didnt notice I did that, thank you so much

Comment: @ChristianHackl sorry if my questions are bad, I am a beginner and still learning to read some errors.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Maybe it's reasonable to not downvote this question as it is well formulated, but IMO the close votes are appropriate. This is a typo, and especially I don't see this being "resolved in a manner [likely] to help future readers." Anyone who has ever called a function in C++ will not run into this problem

Comment: @Vincent: You misunderstand - *I* am not the one who thought the question was bad :)

Comment: @Justin: I'm not entirely sure it's really a typo, and the *"function does nothing"* part in the title may well match someone's search terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 void swap1(double& num1, double& num2);
 void swap2(double& num1, double& num2);
```

In your main function to:

```
swap1(num1, num2);
swap2(num1, num2);
```

And it should work, since you are using a function, not declaring it in your main function.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> cout << "Original: " << num1 << ", " << num2 << endl;
> void swap1(double& num1, double& num2);
> ```

This does not call `swap1`. It is a (re-)declaration, not a function call. Use this instead:

```
swap1(num1, num2);
```